# Apollo Server Express + GraphQL relationships

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, graphql, apollo

I am using Express + Apollo Server + GraphQL + Mongoose + MongoDB to "perform" several CRUD operations on a database.

One of the operations I am trying to make is to get the sites from the database and expand its users with their information for each record like this:

```
query {
    getSites {
        id
        name
        owner {
            name
            email
        }
        origins
    }
}
```

Instead, I am getting these results:

```
{
    "data": {
        "getSites": [{
                "id": "5cae36182ab9b94e94ba9af5",
                "name": "Test site 1",
                "owner": [{
                        "name": null,
                        "email": null
                    }
                ],
                "origins": [
                    "test1",
                    "test2"
                ]
            }, {
                "id": "5cae3a3798c302247c036544",
                "name": "Test site 2",
                "owner": [{
                        "name": null,
                        "email": null
                    }
                ],
                "origins": [
                    "test1",
                    "test2"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is my **typeDef** code for **Site**:

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-server-express';

const site = gql `
    extend type Site {
        id: ID!
        name: String!
        origins: [String]
        owner: [User]
        createdOn: String
        updatedOn: String
    }

    extend type Query {
        getSites: [Site]
        getSite(id: ID!): Site
    }

    extend type Mutation {
        addSite(name: String!, owner: [String!], origins: [String]): Site
    }
`;

export default site;
```

If I `console.log(sites)` I see owner is an array of Strings.

**Edit**:

If I change `addSite(name: String!, owner: [User], origins: [String]): Site` then I get when compiling:

> Error: The type of Mutation.addSite(owner:) must be Input Type but got: [User]

My resolver looks like this:

```
getSites: async () => await Site.find().exec()
```

What's the proper way to define relationships today? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just edited my resolver to this:

```
getSites: async () => {
    let sites = await Site.find().exec();
    let ownedSites = await User.populate(sites, { path: 'owner' });

    return ownedSites;
}
```

And that solved the errors.